# "shaving cream" vs. "shave cream"

Tags: phrases, differences

I read this term *shave cream* in [NY Times](http://travel.nytimes.com/2010/06/20/travel/20hotels.html?pagewanted=2) today.  According to the results in COCA (Corpus of Contemporary American English), *shaving cream* (I also found this word in the dictionary) is far more common than *shave cream* in American English. I would like to know if there's any difference between these two terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [English in general](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=shave+cream%2C+shaving+cream&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), *shaving cream* is far more common:

[image]

However, the two products are the same. Having done a quick [Google search of "shave cream"](http://www.google.com/search?q=shave+cream&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) and ["shaving cream"](http://www.google.com/search?q=shaving+cream&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a), both generate the same results. The [Wikitionary article on "shaving cream"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shaving_cream) also lists the term *shave cream* as a synonym.

Comment: The specific product the NYT is referring to, Alba Botanica, uses the remarkably nonstandard and misleading terminology "[cream shave](http://www.albabotanica.com/?id=65)".  Perhaps the author was trying to combine the two terms?

Comment: Perhaps -- "cream shave" is [even less common](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=cream+shave%2Cshaving+cream%2Cshave+cream&year_start=1800&year_end=2011&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, both terms are correct and both refer to the same product.

However, don't use them both unless your goal is to specifically confuse your audience. When you are writing, use the term "shaving cream" as it is by far the more common and understood term. Public writing is done for the *reader*, not the writer.

Comment: I seriously doubt too many people will get confused if you use shave cream.  Unless you use both terms in the same work.